# AppDelegate's method for supported orientations is not called when UITableViewController is in navigation stack

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios10, screen-orientation

I have an app with a `UINavigationController`. The app needs to allow screen rotations, or not, depending on which `UIViewController` is currently at the top of the navigation stack. To achieve this I implemented an `AppDelegate` method, like below. Basically it allows rotation, but constrains things to `.portrait` if we're showing a `FooViewController`.

```
/// Return .all, unless FooViewController is being displayed
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask { 
    if let nav = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController,
       let top = nc.topViewController {
        if top is FooViewController {
            return .portrait
        }            
    }
    return .all
}
```

This works well, unless `FooViewController` is a `UITableViewController`. In that case, if I have a navigation stack like this:

```
FooViewController > BarViewController
```

... and I rotate `Bar` to landscape, and then tap **Back**, `Foo` will also stay in landscape orientation. The `AppDelegate` method is never called.

If `Foo` is *not* a `UITableViewController`, then going back works as you'd want -- the `AppDelegate` method is called, and it returns `.portrait`, and the screen rotates back to portrait when you navigate back from `Bar` to `Foo`.

So, what is it about `UITableViewController` that causes the system to stop calling the AppDelegate method to check on supported orientations?

Comment: Does it ever gets called after UITableViewController is gone from the stack or you have to restart the app?

Comment: It gets called at later points, and everything else works okay. It's only that it doesn't get called when you navigate back. If it's a plain UIViewController, then it *does* get called when you navigate back.

Comment: Same thing happens with UINavigationController, and probably every container controller. I really don't want to sub-class these container classes